# Is there any faster way to download content from a website?

Tags: c#

This is my code now:

```
private string downloadContent() 
        {
            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = "GET";
                response = request.GetResponse();
                Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
                reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                string content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                return content;
            }
            catch
            {
                return error;
            }
        }
```

This is the site:

```
http://chatroll.com/testings
```

I did that when I'm writing something there in the chat so that every n seconds it will show me what I wrote in my program textBox1 and also write it on a text file logger on my hard disk.

The problem is that sometimes if I'm typing something very fast in the chat (for example: hello(enter),Hi(enter),Daniel(enter)) sometimes Hi will not be shown in my program.  I don't think the content of what I'm typing is being read fast enough.

Is there any faster way to download the page source and handle it? Maybe the way I'm downloading it is not so fast?

You can see my project here:

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=3B8A7D9F66FF985B!171&authkey=!AFO6EmoF38MtkKQ

Comment: In addition to the problem you have outlined in your question, you also have some resource leaks going on. Consider using the `using` statement on all of the `IDisposable` objects in that method, most notably the `Stream` and `StreamReader` objects.

Comment: Why are you not using an API instead of screen-scraping? So you can do a push instead of a pull?

Comment: Erno could you please show mexample how to use screen-scraping on my code instead of API ? I thought on this before but never found realy how to do it so i tried this way im doing it now.

Comment: Platinum Azure do you mean im not Disposing the Stream and Streamreder in the right places or at all ?

Comment: @Daniel, it doesn't look like they *have* a public API.

Comment: codesparkle yeah i think so too i didnt find any too. Maybe there is a way to connect or using the java script in the source code of the page ? Or java is not the case the problem ?

Comment: You can consider to use LibCurlNet. It is based on cUrl and very fast.

Comment: @DanielLip Right, you're not disposing the Stream and StreamReader at all. The references are local to the method and never get disposed, so they leak. Then again, maybe you just knocked up a quick sample and in your real code you do it properly. I find `using` statements to be really easy and convenient, though, and they prevent OS resources from leaking and possibly running out in the worst case.

Answer (score 6):

Why not use the higher-level WebClient? I don't know if it's faster, but at least it's less error-prone. You need to pay attention to the [`using`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statement to release any resources (sockets and the like).

```
using (var downloader = new WebClient())
{
    string result = downloader.DownloadString(url);
}
```

---

Edit regarding performance: if the web server supports compression such as GZIP, you may want to make use of that:

1. Set the [header](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx):

   ```
   downloader.Headers["Accept-Encoding"] = "gzip";
   ```
2. Use [`WebClient.DownloadData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xz398a3f.aspx) to load the compressed response into a `byte[]`.
3. Decompress it using [`GZipStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.gzipstream.aspx)

---

Another edit: your BackgroundWorker.DoWork looks horrible: you have lots of redundant code, heaps of unnecessary loops, etc. I would *strongly* suggest you open up a question at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) and post that method.
By the way, you are calling your downloading code *twice* on every iteration.

Comment: This should be a comment; it doesn't really answer his question (unless it actually is faster).

Comment: @codesparkle I didn't say that it's not valuable, but the point is that your answer is more of a side issue, it doesn't directly answer his question, and so it's more suited for a comment. But there's no needing for flagging, it is valuable advice, just not in the right form IMO.

Comment: @codesparkle - changing from a known bottlenecked lib to a wrapper of a known bottlenecked lib is definately a step in the wrong direction.

Comment: @codesparkle - Question states "Is there any faster way to download content from a website?" And yes, there most certainly is, but changing from `WebRequest` to `WebClient` isn't one of them.

Answer (score 1):

*Just a few thoughts*

1- Set `request.Proxy` to null. This may help in some speedup.

2- In function `Conditions` use `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` instead of string operations

3- Don't use string operations to parse html (like in `GetProfileNames` or `GetTextFromProfile`). Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead. For example:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(page);
var text = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("img")
    .Where(x => x.Attributes["class"].Value="????????")
    .Select(x=>x.InnerText)
    .ToArray();
```